# Mongoose MultiDB Approach - Connection errors from time to time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am dealing with a MongoDB / Mongoose error that i can not solve.
My application is a multi tenant application where each tenant gets its own database. I am dynamically generating the connection endpoint.

I am using the following configuration for the connection:

```
var con = mongoose.createConnection(baseUri, { 
                            server: { 
                                poolSize: 1,
                                auto_reconnect: true,
                                socketOptions: { 
                                    keepAlive: 1, 
                                    connectTimeoutMS: 10000,
                                    socketTimeoutMS: 10000
                                }
                            }});
```

When i create the model i am passing the connection to the model and i add the model to the request, so I can access it wherever i need it in my application. This happens as follows:

```
var Adress = require('../models/adress')(req.con);
models[req.decoded.username]['Adress'] = Adress;
req.adress = Adress;
```

The application runs fine and i can see in the logs that the connection is reestablished when it times out.

From time to time the application crashes with the following error:
{ [MongoError: topology was destroyed] name: 'MongoError', message: 'topology was destroyed' }

Can anybody tell me what i have to do in order to analyze and solve this crash ?
It seems that even after the request has finished, the connection still remains active...

Thanks!

Br,
Martin

Comment: I think that its not a good design to create a db connection on each and every request based on tenants.

Comment: Since you create the connection manually, you should destroy it manually as well.